# How can I open a series of files (PNGs) from a specified directory (randomly) using Python?

Tags: python, random, shuffle

I have a folder in a specified directory containing several PNGs that need to be opened *randomly*. I can't seem to get `random.shuffle` to work on the folder. I have thus far been able to `print` the contents, but they need to also be randomized so when they are opened, the sequence is unique.

Here's my code:

```
import os, sys
from random import shuffle

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\Users\Mickey\Desktop\VisualAngle\sample images"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".png"):
            print (os.path.join(root, file))
```

This returns a list of the images in the folder. I'm thinking maybe I could somehow randomize the output from `print` and then use `open`. I have so far failed. Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by open them?

Comment: what about adding the results of `os.path.join(root, file)` to an array and then access entries of the array randomly?

Comment: I want the program to open the images to view. They need to be in a random sequence, though. I know that it doesn't really make sense for them to be randomized when they're all opened at once, but I'll integrate this code into another program where only one image will be opened at a time.

Comment: open them in paint then? or?

Comment: Eventually, the images will need to be displayed on an external screen (likely in a Tkinter window).

Comment: so you just need a shuffled list of filepaths?

Comment: Yes, I need to shuffle the filepaths, and then I need to open the files in the order they were shuffled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*I have a folder in a specified directory containing several PNGs*. You don't need and should not be using `os.path.walk` searching a specific directory, it would also potentially add files from other subdirectories which would give you incorrect results. You  can get a list of all png's using [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) and then shuffle:

```
from random import shuffle
from glob import glob
files = glob(r"C:\Users\Mickey\Desktop\VisualAngle\sample images\*.png")
shuffle(files)
```

`glob` will also return the full path.

You could also use `os.listdir` to search the specific folder:

```
pth = r"C:\Users\Mickey\Desktop\VisualAngle\sample images"
files = [os.path.join(pth,fle) for fle in os.listdir(pth) if fle.endswith(".png")]
shuffle(files)
```

To open:

```
for fle in files:
   with open(fle) as f:
        ...
```

Comment: I like the first method, but how can I then open the files after? I can't use `files.open`

Comment: @Mickey, I will edit,it is just a matter of a loop, what do you actually want to do with the files?

Comment: Eventually, they will need to be opened in a separate `Tkinter` window one at a time in the random sequence we specified with `shuffle`.

Comment: Ah ok, then iteration will do the job

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue - I can't open the actual images. Using `open(fle) as f:` the output is the shuffled list of paths and not the images themselves. When I try to `file.open`, I receive an error that reads: "type object 'file' has no attribute 'open'.

Comment: Where is file coming from?

Comment: I used a different method to open the files. I created an empty list, put the series of image objects in the list by using `.append`, and defined a function that shuffles the images and displays them in my window using a combination of `ImageTk.PhotoImage()`, `.configure`, and `.pack` (I'm using Tkinter).

Comment: file is already a file object so you must be appending file objects not files

Answer (score 5):

You can create first the list of `png` filenames and then shuffle:

```
import os
from random import shuffle

dirname = r'C:\Users\Mickey\Desktop\VisualAngle\sample images'

paths = [
    os.path.join(root, filename)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirname)
    for filename in files
    if filename.endswith('.png')
]
shuffle(paths)
print paths
```